# Dart : The method 'errMsg' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, error-handling, exceptionhandler

```
class AmtException implements Exception {
  String errMsg() => 'Amount should not be less than zero';
}

void main() {
  try {
    var amt = -1;
    if (amt < 0) {
      throw AmtException();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.errMsg());
  }
}
```

I am trying to create custom exception and throw the object of custom exception class. But when I am trying to call the method of custom class exception.

**Error**

dart/exceptions.dart:81:11: Error: The method 'errMsg' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'errMsg'.
  error.errMsg();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `catch (e)`, it means you're catching any errors, so the type for `e` is `Object`.

If you want to catch a specific error, use the `on NameOfTheException catch (e)` syntax:

```dart
try {
  throw AmtException();
} on AmtException catch (e) {
  // Now `e` is an `AmtException`
  print(e.errMsg());
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DhafinRayhan the only point I am missing that the parent of all the object is Object class. So in that case I have use specific object.

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` block in your code basically catches all unexpected exceptions that may occur in your code. And that's exactly why the `e` has the type `Object` instead of `AmtException`.

### Solution 1

You can specifically catch the AmtException as follows.

```dart
  try {
    // your code
  } on AmtException catch (e) {
    print(e.errMsg());
  }
```

### Solution 2

You can catch all exception as in your code, and double check if the `e` is an instance of the `AmtException` to continue with the `errMsg()` call. You can use the following code for this behaviour:

```dart
  try {
    // your code
  } catch (e) {
    if (e is AmtException) {
      print(e.errMsg());
    }

    // Handle other exceptions (if needed)
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Sreelal TS your answers taught me new concept today.